# Python regex to add a character to all words in a string except and

Tags: python, regex

I want to be able to generate `'foos, bars and bees'` from `'foo, bar and bee'` using re.sub.

I can't even get just adding 's' to all words to work.  I'll work on excluding 'and' once I get that part.  I have tried subbing `\b` with `"s"` but that matches beginnings and endings of words. If I use `'\w*\b'` then the whole word is replaced.  I am trying to figure this out using the Python docs, and `(?P)` or `(?<=...)` lookbehind assertions seem like they might be what I'm after, but I am having trouble getting those to cooperate, and the examples are limited.

Comment: How about split the string into a list of words, filter ands, append s and then join back?

Comment: Sounds like that would be more in my comfort zone, although I am taking this as an opportunity to learn some regex, which is definitely not in my comfort zone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works, based on the replacement accepting a callable:

```
re.sub('(\w+)', lambda m: m.group(1) + 's' if m.group(1) != 'and' else 'and', 'foo, bar and bee')
```

It was inspired by [an old bug report](http://bugs.python.org/issue1519638) (second to last entry).

**EDIT:** A shorter and probably more readable solution:

```
re.sub('(and)|(\w+)', lambda m: m.group(1) or m.group(2) + 's', 'foo, bar and bee')
```

It also has the benefit of making it easier to add other words to the exception list, as isedev suggested in a comment.

Comment: if you change: `m.group(1) != 'and' else 'and'` to `m.group(1) not in ('and',) else m.group(1)`, then it's easy to extend to more words to ignore... but I like it.

Comment: @isedev Yes, definitely. I just added another solution that is also easy to extend, a bit shorter and without the repetitions of `m.group(1)` and 'and'.

Comment: I like the power of being able to use a lambda expression. This pointed me in the direction I ended up going.

Answer (score 3):

The below code would add `s` to all the words except the word `and`,

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "foo, bar and bee "
>>> m = re.sub(r'(?!and)(\b\w+\b)', r'\1s', s)
>>> m
'foos, bars and bees '
```

Negative lookahead asserts that it would match one or more word characters but not a `\band\b`. `\b` here, means word boundary which matches between a word character and  a non-word character.

Comment: You talk about `\band\b` but it's not what is happening here. For example `android` would also be excluded (even though it does not match `\band\b`).

Comment: no, op means not like that.. If you have any clarifications please ask it to the op.

Answer (score 2):

Without considering words to exclude, the following will add an 's' to the end of all words in the string:

```
re.sub('([a-zA-Z]+)','\\1s','foo, bar and bee')
-> 'foos, bars ands bees'
```

To pluralise words in a more generic and less error prone way, you might want to take a look at the [inflect](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/inflect/0.2.4) package (for English at least).

Comment: Thanks. I am aware of inflect but don't need it for this task, which has a fixed set of inputs where adding an s does the job

Comment: Any suggestions on excluding the *and*? I've taken what you've given me and tried a few things and it looks like its not as straight forward as I hoped.

Comment: I can't think of any reasonable way to do that with a regular expression.

Comment: @isedev: If you could come up with a way to match `and` followed by an empty group alternating with an empty group followed by any word other than `and`, then you could probably do something… but Paulo's answer is simpler and clearer.